# Calculating ratio of polygon area inside another polygon area (ArcInfo 10.5)

Tags: arcgis-desktop

I am trying to calculate cover ratio for each plot in a neighbourhood and thus there are 2 shapefiles, one with parcel and other with building outline.

[image: shapefile image]
So I want to:

1. Assign each building a plot according to location. I would need some tolerance option since some buildings slightly overextend plots.
2. Add up the area of building in a plot.
3. Divide by plot area.

I am unable to think how to do step one.

I am using ArcInfo, with Spatial Analyst License.

Comment: 1) Spatial join plots to Buildings using for example 'Have their center in'. 2 you can solve with Intersect or Union and Field Calculator

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Spatial Join Plots to Buildings using for example 'Have their center in'

2) (To have a Shape_Area column your data need to be in a File Geodatabase.):

1. Intersect Plots and Buildings
2. Dissolve by Plot ID or Name etc.
3. For each plot you now have Shape_Area which is the area in each plot covered by Buildings
4. Join this back to original plots by Plot ID/Name
5. Calculate a new column using Field Calculator as Shape_Area (from the dissolved features) / Shape_Area
6. Remove join